# ReactJS / JS save / export form input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I save / export form input in a ReactJS/JS powered site. Say I have a form and once the user clicks Submit, I'd save/export it in any form (eg. csv) What would I use?

Thank you

Comment: you could do it with this https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Thanks - I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

i hope [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/) can help you?

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try puppeteer js

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Most things that you can do manually in the browser can be done using Puppeteer! Here are a few examples to get you started:

- Generate screenshots and PDFs of pages.
- Crawl a SPA (Single-Page Application) and generate pre-rendered
  content (i.e. "SSR" (Server-Side Rendering)).
- Automate form submission, UI testing, keyboard input, etc.
- Create an up-to-date, automated testing environment. Run your tests
  directly in the latest version of Chrome using the latest JavaScript
  and browser features.
- Capture a timeline trace of your site to help diagnose performance
  issues.
- Test Chrome Extensions.